# Обновление базы данных после перезапуска сервера

Tags: django

Вопрос такой, почему при заполнении формы и выполнении пост запроса на моей странице не появляется эта информация, а начинает она отображаться только после перезапуска сервера? В чем может быть проблема?

Views.py

```
class CommentFormView(TemplateView):
comments = models.EventComment.objects.all()
form_for_comment = forms.EventCommentForm

def post(self, request):
    form = forms.EventCommentForm(request.POST)

    ctx = {
        'comment_form': form,
    }

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.event = models.Event.objects.get(id=1)
        instance.save()
        return redirect('/event_screen/home/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html', ctx)

def get(self, request):

    ctx = {
        'comment_form': self.form_for_comment,
        'comments': self.comments
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', ctx)
```

Comment: Возможно, вы используете глобальные состояния. Без кода точно не ответить.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev глобалов нет вообще

Comment: Может быть есть какое-то кэширование, может ещё что-то. Гадать можно бесконечно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev нет, я ошибся, дело в том, что в бд оно записывается, а на самой странице не отображается до перезагрузки сервера, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: В третий раз повторяю: причин может быть десятки, если не сотни, без кода ответить невозможно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev код вьюхи приложил

Comment: Я же говорил, что у вас глобальные состояния используются. Значение поля `comments ` присваивается в момент объявления класса `CommentFormView`, а класс объявляется в момент загрузки содержащего его модуля, то есть при старте проекта.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо большое, все понял, получилось)